# Maven modules which no longer exist in a reactor project appear in the Jenkins build report as "didn't run"

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a multi-module maven project which contains nested some other reactor submodules. As result I have a 3 level hierarchy of modules.

In the past I refactored the hierachy, moving some nested modules from one  to another. I modified as well the names of some of the modules.

On Jenkins, the old modules - now unexistent - appear in the build report as "didn't run". When I do locally a maven install these modules don't appear in the reactor summary.

Is this behavior somehow expected?
I mean, are there any setting in jenkins which makes the reactor runner remember old sub-modules?

The "Delete workspace before build starts" option is enabled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried the action **Delete All Disabled Modules** available between **Configure** and **Modules** on the project page ?

Comment: No, I haven't, but it's obvious it's the right answer. I didn't know that action. It seems it's not visible for all project users - some privileges which I don't have are required.  

[link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4561)

Comment: What if that action does not appear on the page?

Comment: I also do not have that option. Anyone know how to enable it?

Comment: Does this option still exists? These are not Disabled Modules they are deleted modules. This is a case of cache invalidation failure. Moving away from this plugin to a freestyle build.

Answer (score 23):

If, for some reason, **Delete All Disabled Modules** is not available, then you can run this Groovy script in **Manage Jenkins** -> **Script Console** (`https://<JENKINS_URL>/script`). Based upon [a script I found on the Jenkins Jira](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4561) and improved with feedback here on Stack Overflow.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet
import hudson.model.Result

Jenkins.instance
    .getAllItems(Job.class)
    .findAll({ job -> job instanceof MavenModuleSet })
    .each {
  job ->
    build = job.getLastBuild()
    if (build && build.getResult() == Result.SUCCESS) {
      println("==> Processing job " + job.name)
      build.getModuleBuilds().each {
        module, build ->
          if (build.isEmpty()) {
            //module.delete()
            println("  --> Deleted module " + module.name)
          }
      }
    } else {
      println("Warning: Skipped job " + job.name + " because its last build failed.")
    }
}

return null
```

How to use:

1. Run the script first without any edits (it's safe, really!).
2. Go through the list of changes to check for unwanted deletes.
3. Uncomment `module.delete()`.
4. Run the (edited) script again.

Side effect: any archived builds that still had that module in the past, will no longer have the deleted module. In my use case this was acceptable.

Comment: oh nooooooooo it deleted my modul "someModuleYouNoLongerWant" on the first run ;)

Comment: That's what you get when you run some random code from Stack Overflow! :-p Additionally, it installed a virus that can only be removed by sacrificing your firstborn. :-D

Comment: small improvement: if you have Jenkins jobs in folders, change "items" to "getAllItems(Job.class)" to get *all* jobs, not just the ones at the "top" level.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a script that will walk over all maven jobs and delete all modules that didn't run on the last successful build.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet
import hudson.model.Result

Jenkins.instance.items.findAll({job -> job instanceof MavenModuleSet}).each {
  job ->
    build = job.getLastBuild()
    if(build && build.getResult() == Result.SUCCESS) {
      println("==> Processing job " + job.name)
      build.getModuleBuilds().each {
        module, build ->
          if(build.isEmpty()) {
            //module.delete()
            println("    --> Deleted module " + module.name)
          }
      }
    } else {
      println("Warning: Skipped job " + job.name + " because its last build failed.")
    }
}

return null
```

How to use:

- Run it without edits
- Go through the list of changes to check for unwanted deletes
- Uncomment `module.delete()` and run it again

Comment: Thanks! Perfect. This saved a lot of work compared to other solutions.