# Jenkins remove untracked file and directories of old job history

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I am a totally new user to Jenkins. I recently came across a product build which failed in which I saw past untracked Maven modules of that particular product being added to the currently existing set of Maven modules to be built.

The actual scenario that had occurred here in my knowledge is that git master branch which previously existed had been changed to another new branch which is now under development. Since the same job is used to build this product, the modules of the past master branch which have been indexed from old job history has been mixed with the latest master branch Maven modules, thus all modules from both branches are displayed.

Is there any mode (for example a plugin) which enables us to clean the untracked Maven modules (basically files and directories) in a manner similar to git clean command, before a Jenkins build while using the existing Jenkins build?

Comment: How is "Goals and options" under build configured?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven modules which no longer exist in a reactor project appear in the Jenkins build report as "didn't run"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852359/maven-modules-which-no-longer-exist-in-a-reactor-project-appear-in-the-jenkins-b)

Answer (score 6):

There is an option ***Source Code Management*** → *Additional Behaviours* → <kbd>Add</kbd> → *Clean before checkout*:

> Clean up the workspace before every checkout by deleting all untracked files and directories, including those which are specified in `.gitignore`. It also resets all *tracked* files to their versioned state. This ensures that the workspace is in the same state as if you cloned and checked out in a brand-new empty directory, and ensures that your build is not affected by the files generated by the previous build.