# How to remove outdated Maven artifacts from Jenkins Maven2/3 job?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

Over the last couple of months I have restructured (renamed) my Maven modules of my project. I discovered some unexpected behavior with respect to how Jenkins treats outdated Maven modules (i.e., they no longer exist in *pom.xml* files) produced by the build job.

This is depicted in the following screenshot:

[image: Picture of outdated modules]

As can be seen several modules are skipped (= grey bubble). Sadly, however from the UI, I have no chance to delete them by any means. Deleting the workspace does not help either. Actually, the problem exists in other build jobs as well in case a renaming of one ore more modules was conducted in the *pom* structures.

The next screenshot shows a German version of the menu options.

[image: Menu entries in the project job view]

Despite I used the latest Jenkins version (2.23), there seems to be no possibility to clean up the ui / modules from this project.

Does anybody have an idea how I can achieve removing this obsolete artifacts without a fresh setup of the whole project or even the complete build server installation.

**EDIT-1:**

There is an offical issue for that at the [Jenkins Project](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4561), which seems to be unresolved up to day.

**EDIT-2:**

I've tried the work arround mentioned in the issue using `http://hudson-installation/job/the-project/deleteAllDisabledModules` in order to obtain the delete view. However, this page does not exist.

Comment: Didn't they disappear after a click on Worskpace, clear Workspace and a new build after?

Comment: Clearing the workspace and build again, has no influence on this view :/

Comment: Do you have access to the Jenkins server filesystem?

Comment: Yes. Root Access on the underlaying Ubuntu Server  is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven modules which no longer exist in a reactor project appear in the Jenkins build report as "didn't run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852359/maven-modules-which-no-longer-exist-in-a-reactor-project-appear-in-the-jenkins-b)

Answer (score 3):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852359/maven-modules-which-no-longer-exist-in-a-reactor-project-appear-in-the-jenkins-b/35011622#35011622) from Amedee Van Gasse provides at least a workaround to your problem.

He suggests removing the modules marked as "(übersprungen)" by hand using a Groovy script. His solution also implies why the use of `http://hudson-installation/job/the-project/doDeleteAllDisabledModules` won't work: The property `disabled` isn't properly set for the respective modules.

Comment: This is a workaround, which works on our server to remove the outdated. However, I am looking for an UI driven approach, which can be conducted by other project owners themselves without requiring administrative rights on the Jenkins server.

Comment: There is a little glitch with this workaround: Archived builds will loose their modules of the build relevant to that build time. Sadly, this seems to be unrecoverable after applying the workaround. Might be tragic for others, for me it is OK atm...

Answer (score 1):

Goto:

```
http://jenkins-ci/job/<projectname>/<package>$<modulename>/
```

and click delete.

look at:

```
http://jenkins-ci/job/<projectname>/modules
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are in the menu of a build. You first have to go back to the project "Zurück zum Projekt". Afterward you can delete the project (Assuming you have the necessary permissions).

Comment: So in the view shown above, you just hover over the module and in the appearing menu "Delete module"

Comment: I've tried this advice ("Module"), but this view only shows "active" modules (blue bubbles), which I can delete there. For inactive ones this is not possible to hover over the bubbles as displayed in the screenshot.

Comment: I just found: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4561 which confirms this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you could try as a last resort:

1. Delete the job, and then recreate it.
2. Reinstall Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks, but recreating the job is not a solution as we have a lot of archived stuff and corresponding log outputs, which needs to be preserved. From other projects I know, that recreating will solve it until the next restructuring appears. Sadly, reinstalling isn't a real option too as this is not the only Job on the server...

Answer (score -3):

Create a new FreeStyle job and use the same command as you expect developers to use:

```
mvn clean install
```

This behaviour is an outstanding bug in the Jenkins Maven Plugin 
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4561

For me it raises a deeper question of why would you ever want to use a plugin for this functionality. It is a DevOps principle to ensure that the developers use and understand the same techniques as are used to build for release.